# Tag new records with number 1 to 6, evenly allocated

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am bringing over a record set that needs to be divided into 6 lists.  I am using the field WrkList to hold the list number that will range from 1-6.  I don't want to manually add the numbers to each of the new records with a repeating squence of (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) as they are brought in.  The WrkList field allows the records to be worked by 6 employees using queries that use the field as the criteria for that query.  In any given day, over 1200 records may be appended to the table throughout the day and would need to have the WrkList field updated.  I want these divided out as evenly as possible among the 6 groups as each new set of records are appended.  Any help on getting started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are new records added?  User entry or file import?  One by one, or multiple/batch?

Comment: I see you tagged this post VBA. Is there any VBA code associated with addition of a new record? Please post the code. And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Check this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21032394/122139 .  (The question is not well worded and may seem irrelevant, but the answers are probably very relevant.)

Comment: Smandoli, The records are added in batches through import from another access database that is out on a web server.  The replies are submitted via a web form.  I have to copy them over into a database on a shared server so that our employees will be able to work them.  I tagged with VBA since  I wasn't sure if this should be handled using SQL or VBA, I am fairly proficient in both, but by no means an expert.  Java script copies from the webserver db into the shared server db.  Your are correct in that I need to distribute them numbering from 1-6 repeating starting with 1 for each batch.

Comment: Correct if wrong, but the "reply" method is not relevant. How do you import? Access Import wizard, perhaps with an Import Specification? What version of Access? Or is this a "manual" cut-and-paste?  I suggest you re-work your question to include all info here and we delete some of these comments.  As it is, your question is hard to answer because of lack of clarity; for the same reason, not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you will open a recordset in DAO that includes all the records for which `WrkList` is Null.  You will sort this by the order they came in, or some other logical criteria - whatever helps your workers have a coherent work queue (perhaps no order at all).

You will go through the recordset from beginning to end and update the `WrkList` field with a variable, `byteWrkList`.

This variable will have a value that changes with each edit.  It will increment up by one, or if it was 6 for the last edit, it will return to 1.

**NOTE:** This code does not specify that you have filtered for Null!  `OpenRecordset` must be based on a query that does filter for Null!  (Or it must be based on a SQL string that does the same thing.)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub AllocateTasks()
    Public byteMax As Byte, byteWrkList as Byte
    byteMax = 6
    byteWrkList = 1

    Dim rstTask As Recordset
    Set rstTask = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tableOfTasks")

    Do Until rstTask.EOF 
        if byteWrkList > byteMax then
            byteWrkList = 1
        else
            byteWrkList = byteWrkList + 1
        end if

        rstTask.Edit

        ' Make sure you are not over-writing an existing value!
        ' Make sure it is NULL, or that your recordset excluded NULLs.
        rstTask!WrkList = byteWrkList
        rstTask.Update

        rstTask.MoveNext

    Loop

    rstTask.Close
    Set rstTask = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then you just need a way to invoke (trigger) the above code ... but your post doesn't really have enough information to suggest what that is.

There are alternate (and elegant) methods to obtain `byteWrkList`, such as using the `mod()` function applied to an autonumber index.  (This is not important.  I just had to get it off my chest because `mod()` is fun.)  Indeed, there are alternate methods to handle this entirely; but this is what I would start with.

Comment: Thank you!  You gave me the beginning blocks that I needed.  I used a query to filter for the null records so as to not overwrite the existing value in the fields already numbered.  It is working smashingly...Sorry that my initial question  was rather loquacious and meandered around what I actually needed to ask.