# How to calculate difference between two rows in a date interval?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to compare data from an Access 2010 database based on a date interval. Example I have  items from various purchase orders and I want to maintain the history of these item's delivery to a warehouse. So my purchase order has a request for a quantity of 10 of a material, for example, and it can be partially delivered in many deliveries and I want to know how this delivery varied in a date interval. To fill the date field the criteria used is the following: if the item had an update in the QtyPending field, I copy the current row deactivating it with a booelan field, create a new entry with the current update date updating the QtyPending field, so the active record is the actual state of the item. So I have a table that holds informations about these items like that

```
   PO         POItem           QtyPending          Date          Active
4500000123      10                10            01/09/2014       FALSE
4500000123      10                8             05/09/2014       TRUE
4500000122      30                5             03/09/2014       FALSE
4500000122      30                1             04/09/2014       TRUE
```

With this example, for the first item, it means that from date 01/09 to 04/09 the QtyPending field didn't suffer a variation, meaning that the supplier didn't make any delivery to me, but from 01/09 to 05/08 he delivered me a qty of 2 of a material. For the second one, from date 03/09 to 04/09 the supplier delivered me a qty of 4 of a material. So, if I were to be making a report query from 02/09/2014 to 04/09/2014, the expected output is like this:

```
   PO         POItem           QtyDelivered
4500000123      10                  0
4500000122      30                  4
```

And a report from 31/08/2014 to 10/09/2014, would have this output

```
   PO         POItem           QtyDelivered
4500000123      10                  2
4500000122      30                  4
```

I'm not coming up with a query to make this report. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can date spans take in more than two records?  What does the `Active` field do?  (More questions to follow... this is not very clear!)

Comment: Your requirements sound very similar to those of an earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26046828/2144390). Check out the answers and see if one of them might help you out. ([My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21033184/2144390) shows how to use a *self-join* to avoid recordset looping.)

Comment: Smandoli, the active field, if FALSE, it's telling that the record is stored only for historical purposes to query the past states of the items. And, if active is TRUE, means the current state of the items, so if I want to query just the actual state of an item, the only thing I need to do is a WHERE Active = TRUE

Comment: Gordon, I don't need successive difference of QtyPending between two dates. I just need to know the difference of QtyPending between the minimum date and the maximum date found for all items that are in the given date interval. Let's say the item 10 of Purchase Order 4500000123 has two records, one in 01/09 and the other in 05/09. In a report from 31/08 to 10/09, for example, I need to subtract the value in 05/09 from the value in 01/09 giving a result of 2. For the second item, subtract the value in 04/09 from the value in 03/04 giving a result of 4.

Comment: You don't really explain what to do if they are more than two records matching your date range.  If you have no concern with these, then simply find the first and last record for each item in the date range with two subqueries (one for the first record and the second for the last record), join them and subtract the columns to get what you want.  In the references that have been given to you in the previous comment and at the right under the RELATED title, there are many, many examples on how to compare two rows.

Comment: If there are two records in the interval, what really interests me are the records that are on the minimum and maximum dates, so I can calculate the difference between them.

Comment: @SylvainL, you are right the solution you gave here on the comments works. I made two sub queries one using FIRST and the other with LAST to obtain the values I wanted and subtracted them. I think that the solution I posted here is much more complicated, I'll edit it later. Thank you!

Comment: @SylvainL, a much better way to do the same thing I posted in another question. After this first attempt to write a query, I thought about a better way to do it. And there it is: stackoverflow.com/q/26465285/2726538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this query that solved the problem, it wasn't that simple

```sql
SELECT
 ItmDtIni.PO
,ItmDtIni.POItem AS [PO Item]
,ROUND(ItmDtIni.QtyPending - ItmDtEnd.QtyPending, 3) AS [Qty Delivered]
,ROUND((ItmDtIni.QtyPending - ItmDtEnd.QtyPending) * ItmDtEnd.Price, 2) AS [Value delivered(US$)]
//Filtering subqueries to bring only the items in the date interval to make a self join
FROM (((SELECT
        PO
       ,POItem
       ,QtyPending
       ,MIN(Date) AS MinDate
       FROM Item
       WHERE Date BETWEEN FORMAT(begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND FORMAT(end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
       GROUP BY
        PO
       ,POItem
       ,QtyPending) AS ItmDtIni
//Self join filtering to bring only items in the date interval with the previously filtered table
INNER JOIN (SELECT
            PO
           ,POItem
           ,QtyPending
           ,Price
           ,MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
           FROM Item
           WHERE Date BETWEEN FORMAT(begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND FORMAT(end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
           GROUP BY
            PO
           ,POItem
           ,QtyPending
           ,Price) AS ItmDtEnd
  ON ItmDtIni.PO = ItmDtEnd.PO
  AND ItmDtIni.POItem = ItmDtEnd.POItem)
INNER JOIN PO
  ON ItmDtEnd.PO = PO.Numero)
WHERE
//Showing only items that had a variation in the date interval
      ROUND(ItmDtIni.QtyPending - ItmDtEnd.QtyPending, 3) <> 0
//Anchoring min date in the interval for each item found by the first subquery
      AND ItmDtIni.MinDate = (SELECT MIN(Item.Date)
                              FROM Item
                              WHERE
                                    ItmDtIni.PO = Item.PO
                                AND ItmDtIni.POItem = Item.POItem
                                AND Date BETWEEN FORMAT(begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND FORMAT(end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
//Anchoring max date in the interval for each item found by the second subquery  
  AND ItmDtEnd.MaxDate = (SELECT MAX(Item.Date)
                          FROM Item
                          WHERE
                                ItmDtEnd.PO = Item.PO
                            AND ItmDtEnd.POItem = Item.POItem
                            AND Date BETWEEN FORMAT(begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND FORMAT(end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

Comment: A much better way to do the same thing I posted in another question. After this first attempt to write a query, I thought about a better way to do it. And there it is:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/26465285/2726538

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of solving this.  The easiest one would be to simply make a query of all the necessary records between two dates, loop over them and insert into a temporary table the result.  This temporary table can then be the source of your report.  A lot of people will scream at you for not using a big query instead but getting the result that you want in the fastest and simplest way should be your priority.

Your problem with your schema is that you don't have the QtyDelivered stored for each record.  If you would have it, it would be an easy thing to sum over it in order to get needed result. By not storing this value, you have transformed a simple and fast query into a much harder and slower one because you need to recalculate this value in some way or other and you must do this without forgetting the fact that it's possible to have more than two records.

For calculating this value, you can either use a sub-query to retrieve the value from the previous row or a Left join do to the same.  Once you have this value, you can subtract these two to get the needed difference; allowing for the possibility of Null value if there is no previous row.  Once you have these values, you can now sum over them to get the final result with a Group By.  Notice that in order to perform these calculations, you need to have one or two more levels of subquery.  The first query should be something like:

```
Select PO, POItem, QtyPending, (Select Top 1 QtyPending from MyTable T2 where T1.PO = T2.PO and T2.Date < T1.Date And (T2.Date between @Date1 and @Date2) Order by T2.Date Desc) as QtyPending2 from MyTable T1 Where T1.Date between @Date1 and @Date2) ...
```

With this as either another subquery or as a View, you can then compute the desired difference by comparing the values of QtyPending and QtyPending2; without forgetting that QtyPendin2 may be Null.  The remaining steps are easy to do.

Notice that the above example is for SQL-Server, you might have to change it a little for Access.  In any case, you can find here many examples on how to compare two rows under Access.  As noted earlier, you can also use a Left Join instead of a subquery to compare your rows.

Comment: I summarized the requirements. I'm working with a SAP report, the ME2N report, to track specific purchase orders deliveries. I'm importing it's excel spreadsheet output to process and track items with a higher detail level. So an item might be delivered in a date and suffer a reversal because of a problem of some type. If it happens, the QtyPending goes from 0 to 10, for example, giving me a difference of -10 in a date interval. So just SUM() QtyPending I wouldn't take those negative differences into account, but it's important to me to know if a given item suffered a reversal.