# Calculating difference between two rows given a period of time

Tags: sql

Lets suppose that you need to track how a Purchase Order item delivery is evolving in a given period of time and that this delivery can suffer reversals for some reason. Than you have a table that has, at least, these fields to hold the data you need: PO, POItem, QtyDelivered, DateFrom, DateTo, obviously you may want to hold more data about an item, but I omitted fields to simplify the explanation. The QtyDelivered field holds the cumulative delivery amount, this field goes from 0 to the amount requested in your PO, so if your PO has a request for 100 units of a material, QtyDelivered goes from 0 to 100. But if a delivery suffer a reversal, it makes QtyDelivered suffer a decrease. DateFrom and DateTo holds the date interval that the QtyDelivered maintained the same value. Suppose that the table holds these records below:

OBS: The insertion order is not always obeyed, that's why I messed up Id's

```
 Id      PO     POItem      QtyDelivered       DateFrom       DateTo
  3  4500000000   10             39           15/10/2014    15/10/2014
  4  4500000000   10             60           15/10/2014    15/10/2014
  1  4500000000   10             55           01/10/2014    13/10/2014
  7  4500000001   10             40           16/10/2014    17/10/2014
  5  4500000001   10             5            14/10/2014    16/10/2014
  6  4500000001   10             36           16/10/2014    16/10/2014
  2  4500000000   10             5            13/10/2014    15/10/2014
  8  4500000001   10             2            17/10/2014    18/10/2014
```

Now suppose that you need to know how many units of a given material were delivered from 02/10/2014 to 14/10/2014. Well, from 01/10/2014 to 13/10/2014 purchase order 4500000000 item 10 had a delivery of 55 units and from 13/10/2014 to 15/10/2014 this same item had a delivery of 5 units, so it had a negative variation of -50 because it suffered reversal. Note that, in this case, the period of time chosen by you is between DateFrom and DateTo of two records, but what if you had chosen 01/10/2014 to 18/10/2014? In this case the period of time chosen by you encompasses records's DateFrom and DateTo dates. How to build a query that calculates the difference between QtyDelivered in a given period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
 Table.PO
,Table.POItem
,(SELECT QtyDelivered
  FROM Table
  WHERE Id = TblId.MaxId) - (SELECT QtyDelivered
                             FROM Table
                             WHERE Id = TblId.MinId) AS [Qty delivered]
FROM Table
INNER JOIN(SELECT
            MIN(Id) AS MinId
           ,MAX(Id) AS MaxId
           FROM Table
           WHERE
                (DateFrom >= @DateFrom AND DateTo <= @DateTo)
             OR 
                ((@DateFrom BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo 
                   OR @DateTo BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo
                 )
                 AND DateTo <> @DateFrom
                 AND DateFrom <> @DateTo
                ) 
            GROUP BY
             PO
            ,POItem) AS TblId
ON TblId.MaxId = Table.Id
```

Note that the inner join subquery is returning only the MIN and MAX Id's for the join to happen, filtered only with records that is inside the chosen report period. It reduces significantly the amount of records to be joined, because the filtering is being done before the join itself. The calculated fields are subqueries that uses the Id's returned by the inner join subquery to seek the first and last records to calculate the difference between them.

In the inner join subquery, the where clause is a little complex, but easy to understand. Note that the period of time chosen by the system's user can be between to and from dates of the records OR encompassing to and from dates of the records. So the first condition (DateFrom >= @DateFrom AND DateTo <= @DateTo) guarantees that all records that are being encompassed by the chosen period will be returned by the query. The OR part guarantees that, all records in which the dates in the chosen period is between the to and from dates of the records will be returned. But it's needed to exclude records in which the To date is equal to the first date of the chosen period and the From date is equal to the last date of the chosen period, so the AND part inside the OR part will guarantee that (DateTo <> @DateFrom AND DateFrom <> @DateTo). The join condition ON TblId.MaxId = Table.Id makes the join happen with the last Id regarding each record that satisfies the chosen period, so you have the final status of each record.